# How do I use NLTK in python and make a pretty table with each word under its parts of speech?

Tags: python, nltk

**this is the code that i put in to run the nltk program**

import nltk     # Import the Natural Language Toolkit
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader, stopwords   #Import the PlainTextCorpusReader Module
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, FreqDist, trigrams
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import re

```
# PARTS of SPEECH Lookup
POSTAGS = {
        'CC':   'conjunction',
        'CD':   'CardinalNumber',
        'DT':   'Determiner',
        'EX':   'ExistentialThere',
        'FW':   'ForeignWord',
        'IN':   'Preposition',
        'JJ':   'Adjective',
        'JJR':  'AdjectiveComparative',
        'JJS':  'AdjectiveSuperlative',
        'LS':   'ListItem',
        'MD':   'Modal',
        'NN':   'Noun',
        'NNS':  'NounPlural',
        'NNP':  'ProperNounSingular',
        'NNPS': 'ProperNounPlural',
        'PDT':  'Predeterminer',
        'POS':  'PossessiveEnding',
        'PRP':  'PersonalPronoun',
        'PRP$': 'PossessivePronoun',
        'RB':   'Adverb',
        'RBR':  'AdverbComparative',
        'RBS':  'AdverbSuperlative',
        'RP':   'Particle',
        'SYM':  'Symbol',
        'TO':   'to',
        'UH':   'Interjection',
        'VB':   'Verb',
        'VBD':  'VerbPastTense',
        'VBG':  'VerbPresentParticiple',
        'VBN':  'VerbPastParticiple',
        'VBP':  'VerbNon3rdPersonSingularPresent',
        'VBZ':  'Verb3rdPersonSingularPresent',
        'WDT':  'WhDeterminer',
        'WP':   'WhPronoun',
        'WP$':  'PossessiveWhPronoun',
        'WRB':  'WhAdverb'
        }

# Read all contents of the corpus
stopWords = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
Corpus    = PlaintextCorpusReader('./CORPUS', '.*')
rawText   = Corpus.raw()
rawText   = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z' ]", ' ', rawText)   
  
# Extract tokens from the raw text
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(rawText)
filteredTokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopWords] 
TextCorpus = nltk.Text(filteredTokens)  

print ("Compiling Vocabulary Frequencies")
print(TextCorpus.vocab())

# Take sampling of the parts of speech found
posTagged = pos_tag(filteredTokens[0:1000])

tblTags = PrettyTable(['Token', 'Part-of-Speech'])

for taggedToken in posTagged:
    tblTags.add_row([taggedToken[0], taggedToken[1]])

print(tblTags.get_string())
```

**This code produces this**

```
+-----------------+----------------+
|      Token      | Part-of-Speech |
+-----------------+----------------+
|       LOS       |      NNP       |
|     ANGELES     |      NNP       |
|    CALIFORNIA   |      NNP       |
|    WEDNESDAY    |      NNP       |
|     JANUARY     |      NNP       |
|        A        |      NNP       |
|        M        |      NNP       |
|    DEPARTMENT   |      NNP       |
|        NO       |      NNP       |
|       HON       |      NNP       |
|      LANCE      |      NNP       |
|        A        |      NNP       |
```

**but I want it to look like this with the words below each proper column, when manipulating the .add_row i can't get it to follow each proper column**

```
+------+-----------+------+------------+--------------------+------------------+------+
| Word | Adjective | Noun | NounPlural | ProperNounSingular | ProperNounPlural | Verb |
+------+-----------+------+------------+--------------------+------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this i.e build a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
my_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=list(POSTAGS.values()))
for taggedToken in posTagged:
    my_map={}
    my_map[POSTAGS.get(taggedToken[1])]=taggedToken[0]
    my_df=my_df.append(my_map,ignore_index=True)
my_df=my_df.fillna(" ")
my_df.head(2)
```